# Spring MVC Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, c3p0

**Great God to help request**

**My spring-dao.xml configuration is as follows：**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="30" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="autoCommitOnClose" value="false" />
    <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="1000" />
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="2" />
</bean>
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-config.xml" />
    <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="org.tobdata.entity" />
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:mapper/*.xml" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactory" />
    <property name="basePackage" value="org.rb.dao" />
    <!--<property name="annotationClass" value=""/> -->
</bean>

<!-- Redis -->
<bean id="redisDao" class="org.rb.dao.cache.RedisDao">
    <constructor-arg name="addr" value="pr.redis.cache.chinacloudapi.cn" />
    <constructor-arg name="port" value="6379" />
    <constructor-arg name="auth" value="HbNZIKizFfYuNV5=" />
    <constructor-arg name="maxIdle" value="100" />
    <constructor-arg name="maxActive" value="300" />
    <constructor-arg name="maxWaitMillis" value="1000" />
    <constructor-arg name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <constructor-arg name="timeout" value="100000" />
</bean>
```

**In the development environment can be normal operation, the deployment to the Linux server on the problem**

**In tomcat in their own eclipse can be normal operation, but deployed to the server reported the following error**:

```
ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [spring/spring-dao.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1110) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1055) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823) [catalina.jar:8.5.8]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.PoolBackedDataSourceBase.<init>(PoolBackedDataSourceBase.java:54) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.<init>(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:74) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.AbstractComboPooledDataSource.<init>(AbstractComboPooledDataSource.java:142) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.AbstractComboPooledDataSource.<init>(AbstractComboPooledDataSource.java:138) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource.<init>(ComboPooledDataSource.java:47) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: null
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.mchange.v2.cfg.MConfig.readVmConfig(MConfig.java:75) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar:0.9.1.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.cfg.C3P0Config.findLibraryMultiPropertiesConfig(C3P0Config.java:157) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.cfg.C3P0Config.<clinit>(C3P0Config.java:143) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at com.mchange.v1.lang.Synchronizer$1.invoke(Synchronizer.java:58) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar:0.2.11]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mchange.v2.cfg.BasicMultiPropertiesConfig.<init>([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;)V
    at com.mchange.v2.cfg.ConfigUtils.read(ConfigUtils.java:63) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar:0.9.1.1]
    at com.mchange.v2.cfg.MConfig$CSManager.recreateFromKey(MConfig.java:153) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar:0.9.1.1]
    at com.mchange.v1.cachedstore.NoCleanupCachedStore.find(NoCleanupCachedStore.java:63) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar:0.2.11]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
08-Dec-2016 10:34:56.193 SEVERE [risk.tobdata.com-startStop-3] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [spring/spring-dao.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.PoolBackedDataSourceBase.<init>(PoolBackedDataSourceBase.java:54)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.<init>(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:74)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.AbstractComboPooledDataSource.<init>(AbstractComboPooledDataSource.java:142)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.AbstractComboPooledDataSource.<init>(AbstractComboPooledDataSource.java:138)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource.<init>(ComboPooledDataSource.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.find(Unknown Source)
    at com.mchange.v2.cfg.MConfig.readVmConfig(MConfig.java:75)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.cfg.C3P0Config.findLibraryMultiPropertiesConfig(C3P0Config.java:157)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.cfg.C3P0Config.<clinit>(C3P0Config.java:143)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.mchange.v1.lang.Synchronizer$1.invoke(Synchronizer.java:58)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mchange.v2.cfg.BasicMultiPropertiesConfig.<init>([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;)V
    at com.mchange.v2.cfg.ConfigUtils.read(ConfigUtils.java:63)
    at com.mchange.v2.cfg.MConfig$CSManager.recreateFromKey(MConfig.java:153)
    at com.mchange.v1.cachedstore.NoCleanupCachedStore.find(NoCleanupCachedStore.java:63)
    ... 47 more

08-Dec-2016 10:34:56.199 SEVERE [risk.tobdata.com-startStop-3] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
08-Dec-2016 10:34:56.199 SEVERE [risk.tobdata.com-startStop-3] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/rw] startup failed due to previous errors
08-Dec-2016 10:34:56.205 INFO [risk.tobdata.com-startStop-3] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
08-Dec-2016 10:34:56.214 WARNING [risk.tobdata.com-startStop-3] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [rw] appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
08-Dec-2016 10:34:56.214 WARNING [risk.tobdata.com-startStop-3] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [rw] appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
08-Dec-2016 10:34:56.215 WARNING [risk.tobdata.com-startStop-3] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [rw] appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
08-Dec-2016 10:34:56.216 WARNING [risk.tobdata.com-startStop-3] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [rw] appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
08-Dec-2016 10:34:56.217 WARNING [risk.tobdata.com-startStop-3] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [rw] appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
08-Dec-2016 10:34:56.218 WARNING [risk.tobdata.com-startStop-3] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [rw] appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
08-Dec-2016 10:34:56.218 WARNING [risk.tobdata.com-startStop-3] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [rw] appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
08-Dec-2016 10:34:56.219 WARNING [risk.tobdata.com-startStop-3] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [rw] appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-8] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
08-Dec-2016 10:34:56.219 WARNING [risk.tobdata.com-startStop-3] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [rw] appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
08-Dec-2016 10:34:56.220 WARNING [risk.tobdata.com-startStop-3] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [rw] appears to have started a thread named [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-10] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
```

Comment: Can you check on java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mchange.v2.cfg.BasicMultiPropertiesConfig.<init>([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;) ?

Comment: The error is because com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource cannot be found in your classpath or there is a instance object created where constructor doesnt match.

Comment: Check the version of `mchange-commons-java-???.jar` in server and development environment. The difference cause this problem.

Comment: I agree with @beckyang. it looks like you have an old version of mchange-commons-java in your application's effective `CLASSPATH`. Make sure you are using the same or a newer version than the one declared as a dependency by the version of c3p0 you are using.

Answer (score -1):

Just had the same issue, you might need this jar: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadc3p0090jar.htm. Simply copy-paste it in the **WEB-INF/lib** folder of your project.

**Edit:** The link is a reference for downloading the ***c3p0*** library (which serves as a third-party for implementing connection pooling).